# Was Idris 1 a Sunni or Shi’a?

Tags: history, shia-sunni

Idris 1, founder of Al Maghreb (Morocco) and it’s Islamization. He fleed Arabia during the Abbasid Era when his brothers’ Alid rebellion failed and were killed.

According to this article in Wikipedia, it implies that his brother Muhammad might’ve been a Shia.

> Ibrahim's rebellion had achieved some initial successes in southern Iraq, but his camp was riven by dissent among rival Shi'a groups as to the prosecution of the war and future political objectives.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really belongs to Islam rather than history.SE. And Islamization of the Maghreb started at the time of sahaba ('Uqaba ibn Nafi' عقبة بن نافع https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uqba_ibn_Nafi) while Idris https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_I_of_Morocco reached al-Maghreb 1,5 Century later.

Comment: I'd also ask what is the benefit on knowing this? ("That was a nation which has passed on. It will have [the consequence of] what it earned, and you will have what you have earned. And you will not be asked about what they used to do.")

Comment: @Sassir I think it’s important (Islamic-history wise) and interesting to note whether the Prophet’s PBUH nearest descendants were Sunnis or Shi’as. You don’t have to agree with the same sentiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idris 1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_I_of_Morocco) was founder of the [Idrisid dynasty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idrisid_dynasty) which according to the wiki page were **Zaydi-Shia**.

According to Rawd-al-Qirtas and [The Muqaddimah](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter3/Ch_3_25.htm), Idris was a [Zaydi Shia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaidiyyah):

> *'Other* **Zaydis say that the imam after Muhammad b. 'Abdallah was his brother Idris** *who fled to the Maghrib and died there. His son Idris b. Idris seized power and laid out the city of Fez. His descendants succeeded him as rulers in the Maghrib, until they were destroyed, as we shall mention in connection with Idrisid history.'*

So according to the above, Idris was a Shia and so was the Idrisid Dynasty.